# Using a resource folder in test project for test string data

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, tdd, android-resources

I wanted to use a resource folder in my test project with **Android Studio** to store internationalized strings that I'll only use in my UI tests.

But as I'm able to create the `/app/src/androidTest/res` folder, I can't create a resource folder such as "values" in it.

Android Studio says that this folder already exists. It exists, but in my main project under `/app/src/main/res.`

So can I create resources available only for my test project, and how, or I'am completely wrong and the reason that I can't do it is that I mustn't do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: `res` is not under `src`, is outside

Comment: app/res/values is created automatically

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder how to have test specific resources. have a clue ? Is it a wrong idea ? Any clue ? I wanted to store test data in it in order to separate it from app data.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue?

Comment: @AbdalrahmanShatou yes obviously as I checked the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32335106/1396264), you are probably using the wrong package in the import statement.

```
import com.your.package.test.R;
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is it !

Answer (score 0):

You can create resources under `/app/src/debug/res` and use them

Comment: Ok, but this build type is used not only for tests. I don't whant this test resources to be built in the app even in debug build. I whant them only in test app.