# Android test raw resource

Tags: android, android-resources, robotium

I have the following folder structure in Android Studio:

```
├── androidTest
│   ├── java
│   └── res
│       └── raw
│           └── test_file
└── main
    ├── java
    └── res
        └── raw
            └── app_file
```

I'm trying to access the `test_file` resource which exists in the raw folder of the androidTest elements. Here's the code inside a Robotium test case that inherits from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`:

```
InputStream is = this.getInstrumentation()
                 .getContext()
                 .getResources()
                 .openRawResource(R.raw.test_file);
```

Android Studio throws a reference error since the resource cannot be found. The exact error is "Cannot resolve symbol test_file".

How can I reference this resource form a test case, which exists on the androidTest resources bundle?

Comment: Did you have a tool that would generate the tree for you?

Comment: Yes, the bash 'tree' tool

Comment: From where are you trying to get your `test_file` ? From a Robotium test written in `androidTest/java` ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By default your androidTest project will include your app's R class, but androidTest's resources will be generated into a separate file. Make sure you import the R class from your test project:

```
import com.your.package.test.R;

[..]

getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test_file);
```

You can also directly reference the test project's R class:

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(com.your.package.test.R.raw.test_file);
```

Comment: I've got the same file stucture as the OP, but `raw` is not generated for `androidTest` variant.

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk what kind of file are you putting in the raw folder?

Comment: @jlhonora a binary file with no extension. Tried renaming it adding some arbitrary extension, which didn't change anything.

Comment: By doing so, the resource ends in the published APK too. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 18):

I had the `androidTest` resources in the right spot (`src/androidTest/res`) and I still couldn't access them via `<normal.package>.test.R`. I spent a lot of time googling trying to figure out what was going on..

I FINALLY stumbled onto the answer. If you're building a `buildType` where you specified an `applicationIdSuffix`, your files are at `<applicationId><applicationIdSuffix>.test.R` !!!!

i.e.

```
applicationId "com.example.my.app"

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

if you have androidTest resources in the right directory, then you can only access them via `com.example.my.app.debug.test.R` !!!!

Comment: Even without `applicationIdSuffix` you should use `< applicationId>.test.R` in case `applicationId` is different than your package name.

Answer (score 1):

See [Android Unit Tests Requiring Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095695/android-unit-tests-requiring-context). For instrumentation test use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` (in Kotlin: `getInstrumentation().targetContext`). Then you can access `resources`. You won't need to import `R` file.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, androidTest resource ids are generated in `<applicationId>.test.R` by default. Since `applicationId` can be modified by different build types and flavors, this leads to different R files location for each of them. This can be changed by assigning explicit value to `testApplicationId` in the defaultConfig of the app's android configuration in build.gradle. It can be useful if there are more than one build types/flavors that alter the appId, but the tests can be run for any of them.

build.gradle (app):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hello"
    testApplicationId = "com.example.hello.test"
    }
}
```

Test files:

```
import com.example.hello.test.R
```